# Does MySQL database require a unique identifier?

Tags: mysql, api

I'm really new to databases in general but could use some advice. I have a database that has about 6000 records (and growing but not crazy amounts). I'd like to build an API so that I can retrieve a property's price history, but have been advised I need a unique ID but I'm not so sure. Can anyone advise?

DB looks like this:

| address | price | date_created | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Address one, main street | £150,000 | 13/10/2022 | new data |
| Address one, main street | £140,000 | 16/10/2022 | update data |
| Address two, side road | £350,000 | 13/10/2022 | new data |

Comment: It's not required, but often it's useful. For instance, you can use it as the identifier in an editing application.

Comment: Generally you need some consistent and reliable way to uniquely identify a record.  The most common approach is a simple auto-increment column.

Comment: thanks, but in the case whereby I'm currently searching for an addresses history using the address, how would a unique ID be helpful?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you will need to add/edit your data using a CRUD, maybe reference other tables, make foreign keys, etc. I recommend that you add a primary key. I've never worked on tables without a primary key.

I can hear my database teacher in 2001: you should always have a `primary key` and `another unique key` apart from the primary one (compound or on a single column) if you don't want your table to be just another excel sheet. And I remember that it was a mathematical demonstration of this rule with injective functions.

Of course, you can ignore these rules, but they are best practice advice for your future self :)

Answer (score 2):

You might find an integer primary key useful, but it's not mandatory.

If the address is sufficient to be the unique column by which you can reference any row, then that's fine. It's called a "natural key." In practice, most of us have experienced that any column you think should be unique ends up not being 100% unique eventually. So a lot of developers recommend adding a "pseudokey" which has no reason not to be unique.

I wrote a chapter called "ID Required" describing the pros and cons of pseudokeys and natural keys in my book [SQL Antipatterns, Volume 1: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming](https://pragprog.com/titles/bksap1/sql-antipatterns-volume-1/).

Comment: For someone coming across this schema for the first time and having to understand it, having an obvious primary key helps a lot. If they need to guess what it is, they might guess wrong.

Comment: They shouldn't have to guess. If the address is truly the natural key, it should be declared as such in a primary key constraint. But I agree with you that a table that has no primary key constraint defined, whether it's a natural key, pseudokey, or compound key, is confusing and is asking for trouble.